# Missing Custom Annotation Grob in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, grid

I was trying to add a custom text annotation grob to my plot according to the website http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3.  I am using this technique so that I can add the text a normalized coordinates.  When I add the grob the text does not appear on the plot.  I had used this procedure before and it worked like a champ.  For the life of me I can not figure out why this one is not working.

Minimal example here:

```
len = 100
pd = data.frame(x = runif(50)*len - len/2, y = runif(50)*len - len/2)

my_grob = grobTree(textGrob('Some Text', x=0.5,  y=0.5, hjust=0.5, gp=gpar(col='black', fontsize=12, fontface="italic")))

rp = ggplot() + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank()) +
  geom_point(data = pd, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-len/2, len/2)*1.1, ylim = c(-len/2, len/2)*1.1) +
  annotation_custom(my_grob)
rp
```

Can anybody help me to see what I am missing here?  I thought it might have been the theme alterations, but when I took them out the problem still persisted.  (Yea, after saying that I could remove them from the above to make it more minimal...  But I am going to leave it in for full effect).  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Just include the data into your `ggplot`

Comment: I can add that in there but is there a way to avoid having to do this?  Sometimes I generate different datasets for each geom and it just seems better to treat them all the same by specifying the `data` argument in the `geom-XXXX` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comment above by RStudent, all I needed to do was choose one of my datasets to feed to the ggplot() constructor.  Although this worked, I was hopeful that I would not have to do that.